# Converting Spacy Training Data format to Spacy CLI Format (for blank NER)

Tags: python, spacy

This is the classic training format.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

I used to train with code but as I understand, the training is better with CLI train method. However, my format is this.

I have found code-snippets for this type of conversion but every one of them is performing `spacy.load('en')` rather than going with blank - which made me think, are they training existing model rather than blank?

This chunk seems pretty easy:

```
import spacy
from spacy.gold import docs_to_json
import srsly

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=["ner"]) # as you see it's loading 'en' which I don't have
TRAIN_DATA = #data from above

docs = []
for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    doc.ents = [doc.char_span(start_idx, end_idx, label=label) for start_idx, end_idx, label in annot["entities"]]
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json("ent_train_data.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

Running this code throws me: *Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.*

I am quite confused how to use it with `spacy train` on blank. Just use `spacy.blank('en')`? But then what about `disable=["ner"]` flag?

**Edit:**

If I try `spacy.blank('en')` instead, i receive  *Can't import language goal from spacy.lang: No module named 'spacy.lang.en'*

**Edit 2**:
I have tried loading `en_core_web_sm`

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

docs = []
for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    doc.ents = [doc.char_span(start_idx, end_idx, label=label) for start_idx, end_idx, label in annot["entities"]]
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json("ent_train_data.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>
> Ailton - `print(text[start:end])`
>
> Goal! FK Qarabag 1, Partizani Tirana 0. Filip Ozobic - FK Qarabag - shot with the head from the centre of the box to the centre of the goal. Assist - Ailton - `print(text)`
>
> None - `doc.ents =...` line
>
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

**Edit 3**: [From Ines' comment](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1966#issuecomment-364681964)

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

docs = []
for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:

    doc = nlp(text)

    tags = biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, annot['entities'])
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json(train_name + "_spacy_format.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

This created the json but I don't see any of my tagged entities in the generated json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit 3 is close, but you're missing a step where you add the entities to the document. This should work:

```
import spacy
import srsly
from spacy.gold import docs_to_json, biluo_tags_from_offsets, spans_from_biluo_tags

TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
docs = []
for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    tags = biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, annot['entities'])
    entities = spans_from_biluo_tags(doc, tags)
    doc.ents = entities
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json("spacy_format.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

It would be good to add a built-in function to do this conversion, since it's common to want to shift from the example scripts (which are just meant to be simple demos) to the train CLI.

**Edit**:

You can also skip the somewhat indirect use of the built-in BILUO converters and use what you had above:

```
    doc.ents = [doc.char_span(start_idx, end_idx, label=label) for start_idx, end_idx, label in annot["entities"]]
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using [this example](https://github.com/rbhambriiit/home/blob/master/spacy_enhanced/train_data_to_json.py), which I found on [this spacy issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2515#issuecomment-408626222). What do you think about it? Your code seems waay easier to follow

Comment: It's pretty similar. I wouldn't filter out sentences with no entities (which are also good as training data) and I would be aware that these conversions will discard entities that don't line up exactly with spacy's token boundaries, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input - can you give an example on what you mean by:  "conversions will discard entities that don't line up exactly with spacy's token boundaries"?

Comment: Also I have seen people doing `disable=["ner"]`. why do they use it for?

Comment: 1) Try an entity span for the first sentence like `(1, 5, "PERSON)` and check what happens. (This actually crashes with `doc.char_span()`, so there the built-in functions are better, but can still skip spans.) 2) You need the parser to set sentence boundaries, but you can disable `tagger` and `ner` to make it faster, plus you don't want to accidentally include the automatic NER spans in the output. In the version above `doc.ents=entities` overwrites any entities, but if you do it incrementally you'd have to watch out that you reset `doc.ents` initially. Or just disable `ner`, which is easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanations!

Comment: It's almost 1 year since this answer was given. Can you confirm, as of now this is still THE recommended way to convert spacy "simple" training format to json?

Comment: Yes, for spacy v2, this is still a good method. (It kind of feels like it's been way longer for everyone, but this answer is really barely six months old!)

Answer (score 5):

```
import spacy
import srsly
from spacy.training import docs_to_json, offsets_to_biluo_tags, biluo_tags_to_spans

TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
docs = []
for text, annot in training_sub:
    doc = nlp(text)
    tags = offsets_to_biluo_tags(doc, annot['entities'])
    entities = biluo_tags_to_spans(doc, tags)
    doc.ents = entities
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json("spacy_format.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

As of spaCy v3.1, the above code works. Some relevant methods from `spacy.gold` have been renamed and migrated to `spacy.training`.