# Build GoldDoc with a spacy offset format to train a blank model with CLI

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, gold-parser

I'm currently doing NER with 3 Labels:

- PERSON
- PHONE
- ADDRESS

I am able to train my model with python code but I want to use  CLI Training which gives more flexibility.

I have converted my data to spacy offset training format which looks like :

```
[
    ["Bonjour\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\ncordialement, Thomas\r\n\r\n tel 0102030405",{"entities": [[70,79,"PHONE"],[56,61,"PER"]]}]
]
```

In order to use CLI to train/Evaluate my model I need to transform these data  to a Gold format.

I'm already aware of below methods but it needs an existing nlp to be used:

```
doc = nlp(text)
tags = biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, offsets)
```

**My Question is :** 
How can I convert spacy offset to gold if I need to create a model with specific LABELS.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the model here for tokenization and sentence segmentation, so it would also work to say:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what will the sentencizer Pipe will do.  Do I need to configure this pipe and call the code I have written in my question ?

Comment: The training format requires segmentation into tokens and sentences. Running `nlp()` on the text produces both segmentations when you've added the sentencizer (or a parser). See a full example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59209377/461847

Comment: I have checked this stack overflow which is exactly what I need but as said on the other question " I don't see any of my tagged entities in the generated json", my labels are not present for each PERSON, ADDRESS OR PHONE.

Comment: I don't think the character offsets in your entities above are correct?

Comment: it's correct (I have removed some confidentials elements) but keep the same offsets, I have used nlp = French Instead of nlp.load('fr_core_news_sm'). I have now my Labels in the output but some lines are missing.

Comment: I can't tell for sure without an example, but that's probably related to the misaligned tokenization issue mentioned in the other comments. You can try `doc.char_span()` for each entity to see whether the tokenization lines up (if not, you don't get a span). You can handle this by modifying the tokenizer or using another method to adjust the character spans.